# Can I use a mock object to test this?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

Pretty minimal here.  I have a viewmodel that I want to test, and I'm not sure if I just need to implement an interface, or if there's a mocking framework that can do it for me.

What I want to do is give my viewmodel an IProcessQueueCommand, and fire the MessageProcessed event which will execute my lambda, then set LastProcessedMessage

ViewModel:

```
public string LastProcessedMessage
{
    get
    {
        return this.lastProcessedMessage;
    }
    private set
    {
        this.lastProcessedMessage = value;
        this.FirePropertyChanged("LastProcessedMessage");
    }
}private string lastProcessedMessage;

public IProcessQueueCommand ProcessQueueCommand
{
    get
    {
        return this.processQueueCommand;
    }
    set
    {
        this.processQueueCommand = value;
        this.processQueueCommand.MessageProcessed += (evt) =>
        {
            this.LastProcessedMessage = evt.Text;
        };
    }
}private IProcessQueueCommand processQueueCommand;
```

Comment: You say you have a ViewModel you want to test. But what exact behaviour in your ViewModel you want to test? For example, do you want to verify the IProcessQueueCommand.MessageProcessed method is called or something?

Comment: I want to test that when the MessageProcessed event on this.processQueueCommand is fired, the LastProcessedMessage is updated.  I'm new to mocking, and it smells like this isn't the a case for a mock object

Answer (score 0):

You can test it using a fake object, or with a mock object.

Fake object: 
an object that implements IProcessQueueCommand interface and exposes a "fire event" method. You can inject an instance in your view model, call the "fire event" method and finally test the LastProcessedMessage property

Mock Object:
exactly the same, but the fake implementation and the "fire event" methods are generated on the fly by the mocking framework.

hope it helps.